# $\int_{1}^\infty(1-\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}dx$ converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, solution-verification, improper-integrals

Determine if the integral $\int_{1}^\infty(1-\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}dx$ converges / diverges:

My attempt:

Notice that $\lim_{x \to \infty}(1+\frac{-1}{x})^x=e^{-1}$, so for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $M>0$ such that for every $x>M$ we have $|(1+\frac{-1}{x})^x-\frac{1}{e}|<\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{e}$ so we have $(1+\frac{-1}{x})^x<\frac{1}{2}$.

So for every $x \ge M$ we have $(1+\frac{-1}{x})^{x^2} \le \frac{1}{2^x}$,

So $\int_{1}^\infty(1-\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}dx \le  \int_{1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^x}dx < \infty$, so it converges.

Is my proof correct?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You established the inequality for $x\geq M$ but used it for all $x\geq 1$. This is not hard to fix. Alternatively, you may note that $$
\left( {1 - \frac{1}{x}} \right)^x  = \exp \left( {x\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right) \le \exp \left( {x\left( { - \frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right) = e^{ - 1} 
$$ for all $x\geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you @Gary, so I can simply say: for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $M \ge 1$, am I right? (I just don't use $\log$ usually)

Answer (score 2):

A continuation of @Gary's observation:

As you have showed, we know that for every $x \ge M$ (for some $M\geq 1$) we have $(1+\frac{-1}{x})^{x^2} \le \frac{1}{2^x}$. Therefore
$$\int_{1}^\infty(1-\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}dx =\int_{1}^M(1-\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}dx+\int_{M}^\infty(1-\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}dx\le \int_{1}^M(1-\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}dx+ \int_{M}^\infty\frac{1}{2^x}dx $$
Since
$$\int_{M}^\infty\frac{1}{2^x}dx < \infty$$
holds, it suffices to show
$$\int_{1}^M(1-\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}dx<\infty.$$
Because $[1,M]$ is closed and bounded, it suffices to show that there exists a $C\geq 0$ with
$$(1-\frac{1}{x})^{x^2}\le C,\quad x\in[1,M].$$

Comment: Thank you Mark! :)

Comment: You are welcome! It is customary to accept an answer, if it has answered your question. Thank you in advance ;)